# How to set a byte array as a media element source

Tags: c#, arrays, media, mp4, mediaelement

So I have a MediaElement:

[image: mediaelement]

This is how to usually attach a mp4 file to the media element:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\schueler\Desktop\videoplayback.mp4");
```

But the problem that I'm having is that I have a database table where the mp4 file is stored as a byte array and what I want is to set the byte array as the source because right now I can only set the filename as a source file.
How can I do it? I can't find a method where I can set a byte array as a source?

Comment: [This MSDN Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b846fd0b-6881-4820-9fd2-4a5e85023380/assigning-bits-stream-to-mediaelement-wpf)  seems to suggest that the only way is to temporarily save it to a file.